# Why do I get the same effects in a glmer when I reverse code the DV?

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme

I have a glmer model like this:

```
ModelResult<-glmer(Accuracy ~ Predictor1* CategoricalPredictor2 +Predictor3 +Predictor4* CategoricalPredictor2+ Age+(1|ID)+(1| Item),data= Pilot, family = binomial,nAGQ=0,control=glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap"))
```

I got an unexpected interaction and an unexpected main effect that look exactly opposite of what I had hypothesized. When I just plot the raw data, it looks pretty much like I hypothesized. I wondered if the DV was coded wrong (1 - 0 instead of 0 - 1), so I tried recoding it, and got the exact same interaction.

```
plot_model(ModelResult, type = "int")
```

[image]

```
Pilot$Accuracy <-recode(Pilot$Accuracy, "1" = "0", "0" = "1")
ModelResult<-glmer(Accuracy ~ Predictor1* CategoricalPredictor2 +Predictor3 +Predictor4* CategoricalPredictor2+ Age+(1|ID)+(1| Item),data= Pilot, family = binomial,nAGQ=0,control=glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap"))
plot_model(ModelResult, type = "int")
```

[image]

Now I am not sure how to make sense of the effects. When I get a positive beta, how do I know what the model is taking to be a high/low value of the DV?

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive
  Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 0) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Accuracy ~ Predictor1 * CategoricalPredictor2 + Predictor3 +  
    Predictor4 * CategoricalPredictor2 + Age + (1 | ID) + (1 |      Item)
   Data: Pilot
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 22116.9  22200.7 -11048.4  22096.9    32275 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-27.366  -0.332  -0.036   0.330  31.796 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Item   (Intercept) 1.682    1.297   
 ID     (Intercept) 5.760    2.400   
Number of obs: 32285, groups:  Item, 359; ID, 96

Fixed effects:
                                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                             0.68045    0.32678   2.082  0.03732
Predictor1                              0.24634    0.09341   2.637  0.00836
CategoricalPredictor2Group1            -1.81495    0.23383  -7.762 8.37e-15
Predictor3                              0.59833    0.11532   5.189 2.12e-07
Predictor4                              0.22698    0.07932   2.862  0.00422
Age                                     2.16690    0.24262   8.931  < 2e-16
Predictor1:CategoricalPredictor2Group1  0.08001    0.05056   1.582  0.11356
CategoricalPredictor2Group1:Predictor4 -0.05602    0.04313  -1.299  0.19397

(Intercept)                            *  
Predictor1                             ** 
CategoricalPredictor2Group1            ***
Predictor3                             ***
Predictor4                             ** 
Age                                    ***
Predictor1:CategoricalPredictor2Group1    
CategoricalPredictor2Group1:Predictor4    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Prdct1 CtP2G1 Prdct3 Prdct4 Age    P1:CP2
Predictor1  -0.072                                          
CtgrclPr2G1 -0.597  0.020                                   
Predictor3  -0.108  0.147 -0.003                            
Predictor4   0.019 -0.118 -0.002 -0.120                     
Age          0.508  0.001 -0.855  0.004  0.000              
Prdc1:CP2G1  0.029 -0.430 -0.050  0.001  0.041  0.003       
CtgrP2G1:P4  0.000  0.041  0.001 -0.002 -0.432  0.002 -0.095
```

Comment: We need to see your data and/or plots.

Comment: Apologies. Edited to add output and plots.

Comment: Your model is binomial. The recoding amounts to change from modeling $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \P(Y=1 \mid X=x)$ to modeling $\P(Y=0 \mid X=x)$.  That should only change some signs on coefficients.